# Increment version number android or iOS class library azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 2 class libraries (Android & iOS) I have tried to manually increment the version in the assemblyinfo file but Azure DevOps when publishing the package using a NuGet (push) to a feed, it does not increase the number.

What is the proper way to do it? 
Ideally, I would like to automate it with buildID.

Again these are android and iOS class library and not .Net standard.

Comment: Have you re-pack the nuget package with nuget pack task on Azure DevOps when you manually increment the version in the assemblyinfo file? If not, you should have do it.

Comment: Sorted and thanks for reply. I have added an env varialbe  in the nuget pack "BuildId" and then I did 1.0$(BuildId) in the env variable and worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Increment version number android or iOS class library azure devops

Since you have tried manually increment the version in the assembly info file, we need to re-pack the nuget package, otherwise, the nuget push task still publish the old version 
 package.

So, to resolve this issue, **we should add a nuget pack task to re-pack the nuget package before we push that nuget package**.

Note: According to the comment,developer9969 add an env varialbe in the nuget pack "BuildId" and then I did 1.0$(BuildId) in the env variable.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi,not sure if i should post a different question. If I have a solution with 10 .net standard proj in my pipeline and I want to automatically increase the version using buildid . do I need a single nuget pack task and do I also need a nuget push task too to push to the artifact? thanks

Comment: @developer9969, yes, you should  a single nuget pack task and do I also need a nuget push task too to push to the artifact.